# How can I make my moving div move by pushing a button instead of moving by pushing the div itself?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I used this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/1/) to implement a groupon (groupon.com) like div on a webpage I'm designing.

My question is, instead of clicking right on the div to move it, how would you set it up so that each div had a button and you have to click the button (located on the div) to proceed to the next div, rather than just clicking the div itself w/ no button?

All help is more than greatly appreciated!

Comment: FYI.... http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/2439/

Comment: That one is bugged :(
You don't need to use _this on the .each of the #box, because there you need to use the #box

Comment: @JulieS: If any of the provided answers helped, accept one of them or let us know if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 4):

I've update your fiddle with your existing code, just take a look at [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/ykbgT/2453/).

```
$('.box button').click(function() {
    $('.box').each( function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        }
    });

    var t=$(this);
    t.parent().animate({ left: '-50%' }, 500);
    if (t.parent().next().size() > 0) {
         t.parent().next().animate({ left: '50%' }, 500);
    }
    else{
        t.parent().prevAll().last().animate({ left: '50%' }, 500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Html Example**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box1" class="box"><button class="button">Div #1</input></div>
    <div id="box2" class="box"><button class="button">Div #2</input></div>
    <div id="box3" class="box"><button class="button">Div #3</input></div>
    <div id="box4" class="box"><button class="button">Div #4</input></div>
    <div id="box5" class="box"><button class="button">Div #5</input></div>
</div>
```

**Script Example**

```
$('.box .button').click(function() {
    $('.box').each( function() {
        var $currentBox = $(this);

        if ($currentBox.offset().left < 0) {
            $currentBox.css("left", "150%");
        }
    });

    var $currentDiv = $(this).parent();

    $currentDiv.animate({
         left: '-50%'
     }, 500);

     if ($currentDiv.next().size() > 0) {
         $currentDiv.next().animate({
             left: '50%'
         }, 500);
     } else {
         $currentDiv.prevAll().last().animate({
             left: '50%'
         }, 500);
     }
});
```

​

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rn2FX/1/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/2446/

Same code, just tweaked so that when the link (or button) is pushed it does the same but instead of using $(this) (that used to be the div) you now do $(this).parent() (since $(this) is the link and the parent is the div)

**Edit:** updated to cache the parent.